# range function does not see $i

Tags: php, range, xrange

I am trying to learn range and xrange functionality by plugging PHP.net code into a code generator.  When I run the following code I am given the error:

> unexpected '$i' (T_VARIABLE) on line 4

Here is the code:

```
function xrange($start, $limit, $step) {
    if ($start < $limit) {
        for ($i = $start; $i <= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    } else {
        for ($i = $start; $i >= $limit; $i -= $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    }
}


foreach (range(1, 9, 2) as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
```

Thanks in advnace for your insight!

Comment: Be sure you are working with `PHP 5.5`.

Comment: The generator works with PHP 5.  Is this the cause for the error? Though PHP.net states: (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0) 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Generators doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php):

> (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)

So it won't work with PHP 5.4 or below.

If you want to try PHP 5.5 online, use [codepad.viper-7](http://codepad.viper-7.com/).

Comment: Ah, so that does not mean 5-5.5?

Comment: Got it!  So the error is with my generator.  Thanks for your help. =)

Comment: I'm usisng http://writecodeonline.com/php  Any idea of one that uses 5.5 instead of 5?

Comment: Thanks! I would give you upvotes, but I don't have 15 points yet.  So all I can do is say thanks. =)

Comment: @Willow no problem, glad to have been helpful. Consider accepting the answer at most ^^